# What is the unit vector $\hat{\theta}$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: vectors, polar-coordinates

Vector addition is defined algebraically as the sum of vector components, and it's usually taught geometrically by drawing two little arrows, placing them head to tail, with the second arrow's tail at the first arrow's head, and drawing a third arrow from the tail of the first one to the head of the second one, and calling that third arrow the sum.  That all works well in Cartesian coordinates, where the components encode translations, and the algebraic and geometric definitions coincide, but fails completely in polar coordinates, where the components encode a scaling and a rotation, and the algebraic and geometric definitions diverge.

In Cartesian to polar transformations, the unit vectors $\hat x$, $\hat y$ are transformed to $\hat r$, $\hat \theta$, with

$$\hat r = \cos\theta\hat x + \sin\theta\hat y$$

$$\hat \theta = -\sin\theta\hat x + \cos\theta\hat y$$

On diagrams, $\hat r$ is shown being normal to a circle and $\hat \theta$ tangent.

What is the meaning of $\hat \theta$?  Is it a unit rotation (rotation by one radian) or is it a displacement by one radian in the tangent along the circle?  Why is it usually drawn as a tangent instead of as a curve along the circle?

Comment: It's the unit vector tangent to the circle, representing the _direction_ perpendicular to the radial direction.  (The "hat" or caret generally indicates a unit vector.)  It is just used as a basis vector, so it does not of itself indicate a "rotation by one radian" or a "displacement by one radian", any more than $ \ \hat{x} \ $ represents a displacement of one meter in the positive $ \ x-$direction.

Comment: $\hat{\theta}$ points in the direction you'd move if you increased $\theta$.

Comment: I think it's a somewhat confusing notation.  $\hat r,\hat\theta$ is just the rotation of $\hat x,\hat y$ by $\theta$.

Comment: The transformation $\hat \theta = -\sin\theta\hat x + \cos\theta\hat y$ is useful for certain applications, not for others. Perhaps you will find some clarification in [my answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3952005/139123).

Comment: That is a very good answer, indeed.  I can see now how the unit vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ create a local Cartesian coordinate system in which the usual rules can be applied for reasoning about differentials.  But in that answer you mention that you can't take a difference of two polar coordinates component-wise, and I don't get that, as I believe that works.

Answer (score 1):

You may use any coordinate system you like within the plane, however x-y coordinates have special features it is worthwhile to know about:

- They extend globally to all the space in a non-degenerate way.
- The tangent unit vectors defined by this coordinates are parallelly transported (this is a notion that requires thinking on the plane as a differentiable manifold). Just imagine putting a coordinate bases at each point in the plane, it turns out these coordinate basis are exactly the same everywhere (i.e. you do not need to reshape the vectors or rotate them to make them match with those of other locations).

The second point holds the essence to your question: "What is $\hat{\theta}$?". It is one of the basis vector of the tangent space in polar coordinates, the other of course being $\hat{r}$.

Note that the polar coordinates do not have the two nice properties I mentioned above. As the point (x,y)=(0,0) has undefined $\theta$ coordinate so is degenerate. Also note that if you look at the point (x,y)=(1,0) then $\hat{r}=\hat{x}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\hat{y}$ but if you look at the point (x,y)=(0,1) you find $\hat{r}=\hat{y}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\hat{-x}$ so the basis is in fact not parallel to itself everywhere.